# Is it possible to optimize update of a pandas dataframe that involves only some rows?

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, pandas

I have a pandas data frame. One of its columns (let's call it `col1`) contains nominal values (for example `A`, `B`, `C` and so on). I have also a dictionary that maps these nominal values into numeric values (for example: `my_dict = {'A':3, 'B':1, 'C':1}`). Now I create a new column in the following way:

```
df['col2'] = map(my_dict, df['col1'])
```

Now assume that I changed one value in the dictionary. For example `C` key is now mapping to `7` instead of `1`. I also want to update `col2`, respectively. One of the ways would be to recalculate all rows. However, maybe there is a way to change only those rows that are needed to be changed. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `loc` and change just the values `1`  with mapping `C` with the newly mapped dictionary key of `C`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['A','B','A','C','A','B','C','A','C'],columns=['col1'])
my_dict = {'A':3, 'B':1, 'C':1}

# by the way you need lambda with map
%timeit df['col2'] = map(lambda x: my_dict[x], df['col1'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 205 µs per loop
```

Now change the value of `my_dict` key of **C** to **7**

```
my_dict = {'A':3, 'B':1, 'C':7}

%timeit df['col2'] = map(lambda x: my_dict[x], df['col1'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 210 µs per loop

%timeit df.loc[df['col1']=='C']['col2'] = my_dict['C']
10 loops, best of 3: 43.7 ms per loop
```

Both having the same result

```
df
  col1  col2
0    A     3
1    B     1
2    A     3
3    C     7
4    A     3
5    B     1
6    C     7
7    A     3
8    C     7
```

And apparently using `loc` is more efficient in this case.